# Qt Creator apparently configured correctly for Python, but still getting undefined references

Tags: python, c++, qt

I'm trying to get my project ported over to Qt Creator so I can start using Qt widgets for UI, but even with the most basic project possible (empty window with a simple #include  and  Py_Initialize(); in main) I'm getting errors trying to build

here is a snippet from my .pro file with the references to python libraries, QtCreator is resolving the auto completes for the things inside, so I thought it was working correctly, but when I try to build, I get undefined reference errors

```
INCLUDEPATH = \
    C:\Python27\include\ \
    C:\Python27\libs\

LIBS += \
    C:\Python27\libs\python27.lib

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += \
    C:\Python27\libs\python27.lib

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
    mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
    mainwindow.ui

CONFIG += \
    no_lflags_merge
```

I'm hoping to get this working without having to install pyqt, because it's working fine in visual studio and getting PyQt working seems like more effort than I want to dedicate to this

have I forgotten something? I really thought everything was set up correctly, but it seems other people get it working when they add the lines to the .pro file, and mine simply does not follow suit.

Comment: `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS` looks weird. Normally there are flags for the compiler. Haven't you missed sth like `-l` ("minus, small L letter")? Or some copy-paste issue?

Comment: I tried -l before the library and it still isn't working, is there a reference to the flags anywhere? maybe I've got the wrong flag

Comment: At first, try to remove it at all.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, am I removing the -l ? that was how I originally had it, and neither setup worked

Comment: No, I mean whole line: `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += \ C:\Python27\libs\python27.lib`

Comment: when I remove that entire line, the same issue seems to be happening

Comment: I changed to using the "add library" feature of Qt and it's STILL doing the same thing, even though everything is apparently correct and the autocomplete sees the functions from the header, there's still an undefined reference error

Comment: So maybe the configuration is o.k., but you have a problem with your code? Have you run uic and moc before? I am not sure if `set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)` and `set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)` woud be  enough.